# SELECT ALL FROM SelectQL WHERE (answer="short" OR NOT length=10000)

Tags: code-golf, interpreter, sql

I've invented an SQL-like language. Let's call it SelectQL. You can't `INSERT` anything, you can only `SELECT`, and I don't have the time for an interpreter. How about you help?

## The Challenge

Write a full program or a function that takes in a database of tables and a valid SelectQL `SELECT` string, interprets the string, and outputs the resulting `SELECT`ion.

### `SELECT` Specification

The `SELECT` SelectQL statement is as follows (optional portions are in curly brackets):

```
SELECT [column] FROM [table] {WHERE ( [condition] {[AND/OR] [condition] ... } ) }
```

- `[column]` can be `ALL` for selecting all columns, or a valid column name in the `[table]`.
- `[table]` is the name of a table.
- The `WHERE` clause is optional. A `WHERE` clause is followed by a list of `[condition]` separated by any of `AND` or `OR`, surrounded by parentheses `()`.
- A `[condition]` is a key-value pair separated by an equals sign `=`.
- `[condition]` can be preceded with `NOT` to select the complement of the condition.
- Operator Precedence: `NOT` has higher precedence than `AND` and `OR`. `AND` and `OR` is executed left to right.
- Conditions involving arrays/lists (`{980, "abc"}` in `data` below) will look for the existence of a requested value in the array, and return the whole array if true.
- `key` must be a column in `[table]`.
- SelectQL query strings are ***case insensitive***.

### Table Format

Your program should take in an SelectQL  database (array of arrays, list of lists, delimited string, JSON object, etc) in the following format:

```
[
    [table name, (column names), [(row), (row), ...]],
    [table name, (column names), [(row), (row), ...]]
]
```

- `table name` is the name of the table.
- `[column names]` is a list of unique strings which are column names. These are the keys in `[condition]`.
- Each column's values all must have the same type.
- `[row]` is a list-like of values. Each row must be the same length as `[column names]`.
- There can be no `[row]`s.
- Elements in `[row]` cannot be empty. Empty strings or arrays are not considered empty.

### Types

There are three types in SelectQL: `number`, `string`, `array`.

Numbers are at least 1 digit in `0-9`, with an optional decimal point with at least 1 digit.

Strings are double-quote-delimited sequences of characters. Empty strings are possible (`""`).

Arrays are curly-bracket-delimited comma-separated sequences of numbers, strings, or arrays. Arrays can be heterogeneous. Empty arrays are possible (`{}`).

## Input

- A valid SelectQL database, and
- A valid SelectQL `SELECT` query. It will always `SELECT` a valid table in the database.

## Output

- The result of the query. The result must have the columns as well as the resulting rows.

## Examples

The examples will use the following database:

```
[
    [data, (d1, d2, 3, ~!@#), [(123, "", {980, "abc"}, "false"), (456, "this isn't empty!", {{},{}}, "-123.4444"), (1, "2", {3, 4}, "five")]],
    [no, (yes, a, 1.5, what), []]
]
```

```
Format:
string --> result
-----------------
"SELECT ALL FROM data"
        --> [(d1, D2, 3, ~!@#), [(123, "", {980, "aBc"}, "false"), (456, "this isn't empty!", {{},{}}, "-123.4444"), (1, "2", {3, 4}, "five")]]

"SELECT D1 FROM DATA"
        --> [(d1), [(123), (456), (1)]]

"SELECT d1, 3 FROM data"
        --> [(d1, 3), [(123, {980, "aBc"}), (456, {{},{}}), (1, {3,4})]]

"SELECT ALL FROM DATA WHERE (NOT d1=123)"
        --> [(d1, D2, 3, ~!@#), [(456, "this isn't empty!", {{},{}}, "-123.4444"), (1, "2", [3, 4], "five")]]

"SELECT all FROM data WHERE (d1=123)"
        --> [(d1, D2, 3, ~!@#), [(123, "", [980, "aBc"], "false")]

"SELECT ~!@# FROM DATA WHERE (3={} OR d2="")"
        --> [(~!@#), [("false"), ("-123.4444")]

"SELECT all FROM DATA WHERE (d1=2)"
        --> [(d1, d2, 3, ~!@#), []]

"select all from no"
        --> [(yes, a, 1.5, what), []]

"select 3 from data where (3=980)"
        --> [(3),[[{980, "aBc"}]]
```

## Additional Rules/Clarifications

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Input and output can be in [any reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- Please explain your answers.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the program with the smallest number of bytes wins!

[Sandbox Link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/18941#18941)

Comment: May `AND` and `OR` be mixed together? If so, what is their precedence?

Comment: I guess column1 = column2 comparisons are not supported by the language.

Comment: Left to right, so `A=1 AND B=2 OR C=3 AND D=4` is `((A==1 and B==2) or C==3) and D==4`

Comment: @manatwork no, not supported

Comment: Can we assume there won't be any spaces between the `column = value` checks?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No spaces.

Comment: What does a row like `[123, "", [980, "abc"], "false"]`, mean, in particular, the third value. How does that work with the `=` operator?

Comment: When you write ''`key` must be a column in `[table]`'', what is `key`? It's the only time you mention `key`. Did you mean `column`?

Comment: @Abigail it's an array/list/etc and queries in `WHERE` will look for the existence of an element equal to the requested value, and return the array. Using the `data` database in the post, `select 3 from  data where (3=980)` will return `[[3],[[[980, "aBc"]]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 473 bytes

```python
from re import*
def s(d,q):
 o,f,c=search(r' (?:all|(.*?)) from (\S+)(?:.*?\((.*)\))?',q,I).groups()
 for x,l,r in d:
  u=str.lower;h=bool;m=o and o.split(', ')or l;y=[]
  for g in r:
   p=0;_,*t=split('(?: (?:(and)|or) |^)(not )?(.*?)=',c or'',0,I)
   while t:
    a,n,k,v,*t=t
    p=h(a)&p&(b:=h(n)^any(i==u(k)and(j==eval(v)or list==type(j)and eval(v)in j)for i,j in zip(l,g)))|p|b
   if 1-h(c)|p:y+=[j for i,j in zip(l,g)for z in m if i==u(z)],
  if u(f)==x:print([m,y])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZNhT9swEIa/51ccmUR8YCrawsRaWV01ijaJgQRI@5CGKW0S4pLGwXFbgqr99e5sGGxsSMsHO757773HcVw1Jldl96jSm02m1Rx0CnJeKW12vCTNoGYJv8OeB4pnfCrqNNbTnOkA2KAXF8WatXYGiOBK2fhyFylOoTGjBI4RBwG/41@wdaPVoqoZepApDfe84BpkCQk5w0LURrcKtUp1PxcTpYr@XCiIywRUq64KaVjAIUAqLPqNCCOqsS431kFbB6jEfv873zHiSU4UlpCRB66VRlhfIyuVARw4YhHwKSgdBHyf6KzDKpdFCsa5QcxLfsuX1tC4QCVyFuN2tc0mPXot8TouGyaFWLBbpCZsJkS6jAu2dJSyNkKYpkrZzGbhKUW4M7Tkks8s@4OsWMFvEHFdrSe2kcygvZezKQV6za4IZ/APuQ092MDc6h3EA0bcc@ULlqEQ971Ky9KwcM6bCDfJBASEHoR@EpvY58D8pE2Tn3Ts2LXDj62P73zkELJ2p0trioUfjvbpLZ5M/YjmLC7q1ErYweF7Wptc1iDrMjCQzivTbNmSMOJhZNV7ZNM6oMdVtClie4VkfeDM5JK8Iosd@qVyTE1aWxIL6Ldbh3Za5bFxVFHkRZ5Hv@OE@5ej09GnKxiensLJxflXcJvCP5PH7cfc8fBq@DqXEE337dJnX1sL3z6PLkbAzs5tnaBN4Ws93YMXs1/6N7T2K/9t3qWfGs4vIOmIsT/23@7wexF16Lwo67RIp8Yp3WWkT/oq1X1MOMhVntJFp750wvhf@yfEx6OF4dmx2wahPp@xY978BA)

This uses @hyper-neutrino's style of input/output, but is otherwise a completely different implementation.

-5 bytes thanks to @cairdcoinheringaahing.

Comment: Assuming a global variable is not allowed.

Comment: I see. Updated as instructed. Thanks.

Comment: [-5 bytes](https://bit.ly/33bKRmd)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Ah, did not realize that tuple assignment is more wasteful than semicolon-separated simple statements. The redundant space before the star too. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 682 bytes

```python
from regex import*
s=lambda x:str==type(x)and x.lower()or list==type(x)and[*map(s,x)]or x
V=eval
E=lambda x:str(V(x.group()))
def f(d,q):
	c,t,w=match("select (.+) from (.+?)(?: where \((.+)\))?$",s(q)).groups()
	K=[[C for C in map(s,y)if{*c.split(", ")}&{"all",C}]for x,y,z in d if s(x)==t][0];r=[]
	for R in{s(x):[{s(k):l for k,l in zip(y,r)}for r in z]for x,y,z in d}[t]:
		if w:
			v=sub("not \w+",E,sub(r'(\S+)=(\[((?2)(, *(?2))*)?\]|"[^"]*"|\d+)',lambda x:str(e(s(R[x.group(1)]),s(V(x.group(2))))),w))
			while len(v)>5:v=sub("\w+ \w+ \w+",E,v,1)
			if~-V(v):continue
		r+=R,
	print([K,[[q[x]for x in K]for q in r]])
e=lambda x,y:x==y or list==type(x)and any(e(v,y)for v in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRtT9swEP7c/IrDm4bdmoq2MG2Zsq4qnSbBQCqIfXA8KW0cGpEmaWKaBCh/nZ1T3tnQIjV27u557rk7u2mlZ0ncu70NsmQOmTpTJYTzNMl008qdyJtPfA9KO9eZ4@gqVbRkXuxD2Y6SQmWUJRlEYa6fOkVz7qU05yWT6C2tU0ctvcgaPWOjp7Rsn2XJRUoZY5avAgiozxfMthpTrnnhzD09nVGSq0hNNdB2i0GtEXd9Rvs2FDOVKXCpcbmM9d8TntMFY2vanDKrse8IMYQAZQwhjGGtq2JhcNWctvM0CjUlHAhbfbgiXhQRPlxJE13yil8ahA9hADnWhQVKsS2/ZI6QVsPEjNF/ZVy2wOWc2VGd6JxHBngZprTiGVsZW1ZbXjCvhJZYbAMTFGZtLJ38YkJJnGhwixbhI26@s03qHreYQ11Bab/LKIemWVmT9V15TcRvIpvk2vVbbJM/67CiOR2L@y53mGTYn8e2IwU@vMDuY/JiFkYKIhXTJfu6a99pQR1w9zN6lrxTB4fBzdYpBtrTJNZhfKHQmLWcMbcaaRbGmop9LsRClOuSTbn79XZhtpmUzFIPp4FXduk4FfzlJIEXV1jGEkdm0EuDLtmtPwEHhNUQxPe0hwOkxO@YOfpd8@6Z183Gt3eEcRC00@3hN9rE50/buPMmUyJxDbwoVyaE7ux@xG89C3MI83hTg5qnutowECG5kCZ6C2naO/jUiA5aTC6B1Ds1WbhELow0quKk1lSp3CgxAkmnvWuWYubpWpWUlrQsPPETtB6PDkbDExgcHMD38dFPqKtiL7x7nbVzb3AyeOX0UVDvDfADtUHDrx@j8Qjo4ZEBOlgYewXAy/BIdw/4V7Dp9Wv6Ht4UOBqD33Vc4pI3cjxFYY7uk9C7229C68uPrX3p6609tdD1XwKmxlGz/@sCylwPGQaHe3UpKPdh2rXu2z8)

-5 bytes thanks to Razetime
-18 bytes thanks to caird coinheringaahing

this was painful

This uses `[]` for arrays because that's Python's list representation. Please let me know if this is invalid. The DB is just taken in the representation given in the question as a native Python object.

Comment: c is only used once so you can inline c.split

Comment: `[]` is perfectly fine for arrays

Comment: [-18 bytes](https://bit.ly/3nKwuyO)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 583 bytes:

```
import re, operator as o
def f(a,q):
 [[c,b]],z=[(c,d)for t,c,d in a if t==(r:=re.findall(' (.+) FROM (\w+)',q)[0])[1]],lambda n,m,w:[o.pos,o.not_][w](n in m if type(m)==set else n==m)
 d=[dict(zip(c,i))for i in b]
 p=lambda e,i:(eval((v:=e.pop().split('='))[-1]),i[re.sub('NOT\s','',v[0])],v[0][:3]=='NOT')
 return (g:=[c,r[0].split(', ')][r[0]!='ALL']),[[i[j]for j in g]for i in d if(y:=lambda e,u:True if not e else(z(*p(e,i))if not e[:-1]or not u else[o.and_,o.or_][u.pop()=='OR'](z(*p(e,i)),y(e,u))))(re.findall('(?:(?:NOT\s)*\w+\=(?:\{.*?\}|".*"|\w+))+', q),re.findall('AND|OR',q))]
```

Comment: welcome to codegolf! Nice first answer! But can you add a TIO link that run the code? this way others can help you golf down more bytes

Comment: here’s a [TIO](https://tio.run/##TZHBbhshEIbvfoppLgw2XTXKpUJCUaSqpzSWotxYFGEvmxDtLpRlbdl1n90dtk1jhAQM8M83/8RDfg3DzdeYzmffx5AyJCcgRJdsDgnsCGHRuBZatOInlwvQeis2xoij0rgVDW/pVRa0Az@ABd9CVgqTVMlVrR8a23XIAKsVh@@P6x@A9X7FGWnpL4bra1LqbL9pLAyiF3upQxXDKEI1hPxs9N7gUIT7WfgQHfZcqdFlcN3oYFCq5wtolG78NuPRR2LyfIby5d/GLCCqfxmc8BLdznaIO6kcJYrIqzF2PiNTjHP9@dpw4TWhj9MG2cP6qR6ZYEzsCq2ZFy1vjFLljlHq5PKUBsAXqciYRPfvggIYN7pEPil2d3/PSFprr99MoXsrdC/mPyjZ1@JBfqBO8ilNrpRNToCb68UjLiO6UuF7XEtiJpFymOZH5KAdmmeyMCRycPpbJhGvH5m5UBAHWidOAy9bhbeS5lw5X1KvakXH@le1vK1/n66q5dWpNJCvSgvF5ce7h28nSkFhbs7nPw) link for your code